# Trying to push git changes to server, why does Putty display the error message?

Tags: windows-7, git, putty

I'm following the instructions on setting up git on Windows from here:

> http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/

When I try to do:

```
git push master origin
```

I get an error from PuTTY saying:

> Network error: connection refused

Why is PuTTY getting involved here?  I didn't even setup PuTTY for this.

I know I used PuTTY in the past but forget what I did; how can I disable it?

Comment: You might have a typo there, it's `git push origin master`, with `origin` being the name of the remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

Git on Windows uses [PuTTY Link](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) to establish an SSH connection required for pushing the repo. If you no longer want to use PuTTY, you should alter `GIT_SSH` to point to a different SSH authorization agent (openSSH, perhaps).

Comment: ok so built-in mysysgit won't have that?  i have to download another app?

Comment: mine has \tortoisesvn\sbin\tortoiseplink.exe, what should I change this too then?  hoping mysysgit has something built in.

Comment: it should be openssh, I'll update that later. Any reason you want to move away from Puttylink? @user27449

Comment: no reason, just wanted an easier setup i.e built in.  I used putty before like 1+ years ago and don't remember what I did to set it up, now i'm using my on vps server for git.

Comment: how did my git_ssh get set to my SVN's TortoisePlink.exe?  Where is the build in one then?